# Draw the acceleration time graph of a body which thrown vertically upwards at 20 m/s and then comes back down

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity

I have considered velocity to be positive while going up and negative while coming down. So I think the graph is a straight line a $y=-9.8 m/s^2$ parallel to the x (time) axis because velocity technically decreases while coming down as it goes from 0 to -20. But is this right or should acceleration be negative while going up and positive while coming down? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first intuition was right, but here's a simpler way to explain why it is. Acceleration, a result of Earth's gravity acting on the body, can be considered to be constant. Now, since gravity always points down and you defined the downward direction as negative, $\text{acceleration}=g=-9.8$ m/s<sup>2</sup> (as you may know, $g$ here means the local value of acceleration due to gravity), which means your acceleration–time graph *is* a single horizontal line.

What actually happens in the context of the problem? Well, throughout the motion of the body, the only force on the body that you need to consider is the constant gravitational force in the negative direction. When it's rising, velocity changes at $-9.8$ m/s<sup>2</sup> (decreases at $9.8$ m/s; acceleration and velocity have opposite directions) from $20$ m/s to $0$ m/s. As it falls, it decreases the same way, just from $0$ to $-20$ m/s (it becomes more negative because acceleration and velocity have the same direction).

Comment: Thank you for your help